# view comments in repository using tortoise svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

How can I easily view comments in a repository using Tortoise SVN?

I would like the most simple steps to see the comments associated with each revision. I do prefer using GUI always.

I'm quite new to SVN so this might be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click - TortoiseSVN - Show log.

Comment: Thanks a million! On my side it is Right click - SVN Checkout ... > Show log.

Comment: @tech that's only because you're right-clicking in a directory that isn't part of a working copy. If you right-click in a working copy, the advice given holds true. You can also get there from the Repository Browser.